# How to keep the pedometer awake on Android apps while the app is backgrounded?

Tags: android, flutter

I have a pedometer app, but on devices that do not have Google Fit installed, the pedometer falls asleep when the app is killed. I have managed to avoid this by using a foreground service, but foreground services increase the battery consumption. Is there any way to force the pedometer to stay on, even when Google Fit is not installed?

Comment: You will need to use foreground service with WorkManager to achieve this requirement. You can ask ChatGPT regarding the same and you will get proper answer.